# OCaml Stackoverflow Error when printing list

Tags: list, printing, ocaml

I am trying to print a list in OCaml. My list consists of elements of a structure I defined called Elem. Somewhere I am getting a stack overflow error and I cannot figure it out.

```
let rec pretty_print tr =
    let rec trc_list_to_str trc out = match trc with
      | [] -> out
      | t::ts -> trc_list_to_str ts (out ^ pretty_print t)
    in "[" ^ pretty_print tr ^ "]"

  and print_single_trace (st: Ast.Elem.t) =
    PrettyPrinting.print_identifier st.label ^
    PrettyPrinting.print_literal st.payload
```

Comment: it looks like you swapped `t` and `ts`. try with `ts::t` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, the `trc_list_to_str` function is unused, the `pretty_print_trace` function can thus be read as

```
let rec pretty_print_trace tr =
  in "<Trace>\n" ^ pretty_print_trace tr ^ "\n</Trace>\n"
```

Therefore, the `pretty_print_trace` functions calls itself infinitely without ever looking at its argument trying to compute 
`<Trace><Trace><Trace><Trace> … × ∞ </Trace></Trace></Trace></Trace>`